# Is it necessary to inform HR about returning to work after long medical leave?

Tags: communication, india, software, leave

I working in a MNC company. I met road accident and took permission from HR for 3-4 weeks
medical leave. Now I am fully recovered and ready for work. Is it necessary to inform HR about
returning to work ?

Comment: It will depend heavily on the workplace culture. Given that HR granted you "permission", you should keep them in the loop. They may require you get a "fit for work" certificate as well.

Comment: In my culture (UK), salaried staff returning from sick leave have to simply arrive at work when they are better. Their line manager will then carry out the return-to-work process, e.g. meet with staff member, update attendance status on HR system, etc. At the meeting the manager will make sure the person is really fit for work, and whether any adjustments to work patterns will be needed, e.g. short hours for a while, special chair, etc. The HR system or team will advise the manager if any absence management triggers have been reached due to number of absences.

Comment: ...if working from home, the returning member would notify their line manager as soon as logging in at the start of their first day. Usually, the line manager handles contact with HR for routine matters like sick absence, and the staff member would not be expected to contact HR directly.

Comment: Why would you not want to tell HR you are coming back to work? Assume you get paid for six months when absent for health reason, and in five months your salary stops because HR didn’t know you are back.

Comment: It might be worth finding out whether you require a doctor's note that you are in fact fit to return to work.  I'm sure the company doesn't want the liability of an injury at the workplace if your self-assessment is incorrect.

Comment: I cannot imagine any scenario where you would not inform HR. That's...what they do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it *neccessary*? Well, we don't really know. There might be laws, or regulations, or company policy.

But look at it the other way: if you were in contact with HR about this before, and you have acted in the way discussed, would it hurt to sent a short mail? Could anything bad come from it? Even if there is no law or policy mandating it, wouldn't it just be good style to do it?

> Hello $Name-Of-HR-Person,
>
> as previously discussed in the mail from dd/mm/yyyy I was on medical leave for the last X days. I am fit for work now and will be back on dd/mm/yyyy.
> Thanks for making this as easy as possible, I'm really looking forward to being back at work again.

Done. Don't forget to inform your direct supervisor and team, too. You showing up for work should not come as a surprise to *anybody* in the company. It's not a big deal unless you make it a big deal. Just communicate with people.

Comment: Maybe it's because my employer has a large workforce, 15,000 employees, or practices differ (I'm UK), but 'HR' with us is very much a back-office section. Line management hire, fire, manage attendance, conduct, disability, etc,  HR update records accordingly. They are outsourced like payroll, IT, & employee health services. Everything is always via who you report to, e.g. your line manager or team leader. I might go a whole year without hearing from HR. I told my team leader of my planned retirement date and she notified HR who created documentation and triggered the pension team calculation.

Comment: Likewise absence for sick reasons. A person's manager creates a recruitment/dismissal/retirement ticket on the HR system. You don't know who is dealing with it. They are in South Wales, 50 miles away.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it necessary to inform HR about returning to work ?*

**Why is that a question?**

You already had them involved when you availed the leave, so once that leave is over and you're ready to join back, it comes naturally that you'll have them looped.

Don't overthink it, drop an email thanking them for the support this far, and letting them know that you're ready to be back to work on so-and-so date. Don't forget to loop in your manager, too.